# Confused to get that 2^(n^2 )=Θ(2^(n^3 ))?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Can anyone help me to understand that Is 2^(n^2 )=Θ(2^(n^3 )) ? it will be great if also provide the proof for this. As per my view this does not need to be equal.

Comment: Wrong site, post it on maths site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Comment: The thing you're trying to prove isn't true.

Comment: What's up with your tags? What does a numerical computation library for Python have to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given assumption is not true:
[image: Disprove]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `2^(n^2)` is a function and `Theta(2^(n^3))` is a set of functions, so it would be correct to say that `2^(n^2) ∈ Theta(2^(n^3))`. The `=` is just a common abuse of notation, but it actually means `∈`. To find out whether that statement is true, solve the following limit:

```
lim (n->infinity) of (2^(n^2)) / (2^(n^3))
```

If the result is 0 or infinite then the function does not belong to that particular Theta class. If it is some other value, it does belong to that class.